# CoreMotion to Move Slider

Tags: ios, swift, slider, gravity, core-motion

I have a slider at the bottom of my screen. It has a fixed Y but can move either way in the X direction. I wanted to use CoreMotion to move the slider back and forth when the phone is tilted. I got the sense that I might need a gravity behavior and DeviceMotion, but I'm not quite sure exactly how to do this. Somebody please help. To give a picture of what things look like, I have provided an image below. Ignore the ball. It currently has no relevance.

[image]